# how to close modal clicking outside in react

Tags: reactjs

```
{import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal } from 'reactstrap';

class ContactUsSuccessPopup extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modal: true
        };
    }

    toggle = () => {
        this.props.hideModal(!this.state.modal)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal}
                    toggle={this.toggle}
                    className="welcome_popup_container"
                >
                    <div className="welcome_popup">
                        <div className="welcome_popup_main">
                            <div className="popup_right">
                                <h2>Welcome</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default ContactUsSuccessPopup;
```

**I am using reactstarp modal, how can i make the modal close when i click outside? right now it close only if i click the dismiss button and up and bottom of modal. If I click left and right of the modal the modal doesn't close**
Version ***"react": "^16.8.1" and "reactstrap": "^6.4.0"***

Answer (score 0):

Update the `toggle` method to properly change your state:

```
toggle() {
    this.setState({modal: !this.state.modal})
}
```